# Convert hard disk installation of Ubuntu 15.10 to live cd/ iso

Tags: 15.10, live-cd

I have installed lots of apps and tools on my Ubuntu 15.10. Now I want to create iso of this installation.

So that I can share with colleagues. I tried this

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch,

but installation did not proceed from this iso image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Answer (score 0):

You could try: [pinguy-os](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/).

That basically lets you clone the running instalation to a live CD/DVD.

Note there are caveats around the maximum size things can be, and like with all live systems, performance is liable to suck.

Might be worth looking at for you though

You might also like to check out [UCK](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/uck/).

Not exactly what you wanted, but it might provide some insight into the process and help you refine what you want.